# Box has 3 red, 2 green, 1 yellow and 1 white balls. I pick a ball, return it and then pick another.

Tags: probability

Box has 3 red, 2 green, 1 yellow and 1 white balls. I pick a ball, return it and then pick another. What is the probability of not getting a single green ball?

Any help would be appreciated since I don't have a clue how to solve this.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I wish that were true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first pick,
probability of not getting a single green ball = $\cfrac{5}{7}$

In second pick pobability is going to be same = $\cfrac{5}{7}$

$P = \cfrac{5}{7} * \cfrac{5}{7} =\cfrac{25}{49}  $

Comment: So probability of getting 2 greens would be 4/49. May I ask what is the probability of getting at least 1 green?

Comment: 1- P(no green balls)

Answer (score 0):

There are a total of 7 balls (3+2+1+1), so if you pick a random ball n times, then the probability of not getting a green ball every time would be:

$ (5/7)^n $

since its a 5/7 every time, and you multiply the probability.

If you do two turns, then the probability of getting one green at least would be:

The probability of getting it on the first turn and not the second +

The probability of getting it on the second turn and not the first +

The probability of getting it both times

Which is:
$(2/7*5/7)$ + $(5/7*2/7)$ + $(2/7*2/7) = 24/49$